# Form POST data handling with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have hard time figuring out how to recieve form data. This is how my form looks like:

```
<form action="register" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_form">
 <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
 <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
</form>
```

How can I access the data of my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your form action to something like this:

```
action="<?= esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')) ?>"
```

And add a hidden input in your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
```

And then in your backend class add an action like this:

```
namespace Class\Namespace;

class ClassName {

    public function init() {
        add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', [$this, 'handleForm'] );
    }

    public function handleForm() {
        // your logic here
        // use $_POST to retrieve post data
    }
....
```

Make sure to include your class in your `functions.php` of your theme, like this:

```
(new \Class\Namespace\ClassName)->init();
```

To read form data, then in your `handleForm` method just use `$_POST`.

For more examples have a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) page.

Comment: I have given my form submit button `name = "submit"` and got the form data by checking if `$_POST["submit"]` exists in  my `admin-post.php` file. Is this a bad practice and if yes why.

Comment: If by that you mean, you changed something in the `admin-post.php` file itself, it's a very bad practice. You should never, ever, change a core file in any framework. But was my answer clear enough or you need me to add more detail to it? :)

Comment: Where can I write this code `public function init() {
    add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
}`

Comment: You can create a class under your theme folder and then include it in `functions.php` - anyway, I'll expand my answer later today when I get some time.

Answer (score 1):

After the form has been submitted, you can access it on the page it loads with the PHP [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable.

eg.

```php
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Remember to [validate and sanitise](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) this variable as it will be what the user has entered.